# Split list in and then join elements in sublists

Tags: python

Given the following list:

```
my_list = ['A > 1', 'B > 2', '\n', 'C > 3', 'D > 4', '\n', 'E > 5', 'F > 6', '\n']
```

I would like to split at the "\n" which I intentionally appended for this goal.

So I'm trying to get something similar to:

```
my_list2 = [['A > 1', 'B > 2'], ['C > 3', 'D > 4'], ['E > 5', 'F > 6']]
```

And then I would like to join each sublist with a white space in between, as in:

```
my_list3 = [['A > 1 B > 2'], ['C > 3 D > 4'], ['E > 5 F > 6']]
```

It might be something easy to do, but I've been trying already for several hours and I can't figure out how to do it. I've been googling and also saw some questions here in Stackoverflow talking about using `intertools.groupby`, but I have not been able to replicate the same results.

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't tell us you're tried for hours; show what you're trying that's not working.

Comment: Well... I meant I tried several approaches, some of them quite complicated considering the task. If I showed them all I'd need to make quite a long post explaining every single thing that did not work and I would need to paste a big chunk of source code, as this is done in a nested `for` loop.

I did try with `groupby` from examples I saw in other posts here, actually quite similar to the answers below, but it seems I always had an argument misplaced.

I'm sorry but I was trying to make the question as clear as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend staying away from the join-to-string-and-then-split-again answers. `groupby` (or the equivalent for loop) is better

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> my_list = ['A > 1', 'B > 2', '\n', 'C > 3', 'D > 4', '\n', 'E > 5', 'F > 6', '\n']
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(my_list, "\n".__ne__) if k]
[['A > 1', 'B > 2'], ['C > 3', 'D > 4'], ['E > 5', 'F > 6']]
```

You can go straight to the final step like this

```
>>> [" ".join(g) for k, g in groupby(my_list, "\n".__ne__) if k]
['A > 1 B > 2', 'C > 3 D > 4', 'E > 5 F > 6']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly... `groupby` seems quite complicate to use even after going through some examples, I guess I'll have to get used to it!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach for going straight to your expected `my_list3`:

```
>>> my_list = ['A > 1', 'B > 2', '\n', 'C > 3', 'D > 4', '\n', 'E > 5', 'F > 6', '\n']
>>> [[x] for x in ' '.join(my_list).strip().split(' \n ')]
[['A > 1 B > 2'], ['C > 3 D > 4'], ['E > 5 F > 6']]
```

If you don't need to wrap each element in its own list it is simpler because you don't need the list comprehension:

```
>>> ' '.join(my_list).strip().split(' \n ')
['A > 1 B > 2', 'C > 3 D > 4', 'E > 5 F > 6']
```

If you really do need to calculate the intermediate list as well:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(my_list, lambda x: x != '\n') if k]
[['A > 1', 'B > 2'], ['C > 3', 'D > 4'], ['E > 5', 'F > 6']]
```

Comment: Almost the exact same why I did it. But yours is cleaner and makes the subarrays.

Comment: The split/join way doesn't work well if there are two `'\n'` in a row.

Answer (score 1):

if you want list of lists you can do:

```
>>> [[i.strip()] for i in " ".join(my_list).strip().split("\n")]
[['A > 1 B > 2'], ['C > 3 D > 4'], ['E > 5 F > 6']]
```

if you want only strings you can do:

```
>>> [i.strip() for i in " ".join(my_list).strip().split("\n")]
['A > 1 B > 2', 'C > 3 D > 4', 'E > 5 F > 6']
```